# PostgreSQL password issue with psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to setup PostgreSQL onto a CentOS (that I connect through SSH). I need to unzip a package (so not downloading through yum or rpm): http://get.enterprisedb.com/postgresql/postgresql-9.3.4-3-linux-x64-binaries.tar.gz and set this up.

I unzipped, and ran the following

```
./postgresql-9.3/bin/initdb -D data/
./postgresql-9.3/bin/postgres -D data/
```

When I try to run `./postgresql-9.3/bin/psql` or `createuser` I get asked for a password and I enter it, but get:
`psql.bin: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "myusername"`

**Question**: How can I make `psql` and `createuser` work?

*Additional info*

My `./data/pg-hba.conf` is as follows:

```
local all all trust
host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust
host all all ::1/128 trust
```

Also, there doesn't seem to be a `postgres` user in the system, which makes sense since I simply unzip the tar.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, postgres users and your operating system users are not the same thing, except by default.

Unless you create an actual `postgres` system account on your computer, you will need to edit your `pg_hba.conf` file and set up your authentication methods.  The default should have a line something like

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

Which tells it to let the `postgres` super user log in locally if the person running psql is using an operating system account also named `postgres`.  If you change `peer` to `trust` then it will allow anyone to log in locally with `psql -U postgres`.  Once you can connect, you'll be able to create other users with their passwords.

Once things are set up, for security you should set a password on the `postgres` user, then change `trust` to `md5` to require the password to connect.

Comment: When I put `local all postgres peer`, restart the postgres instance, and try `bin/psql` I get `FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"` and a log statement saying `LOG: provided username (postgres) and authenticated username (myusername) do not match`          
When I put `local all postgres trust` instead, I get `FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist`

Comment: Try redoing `initdb` with `-U postgres` to set the superuser name

Comment: Yep, this did the trick, finally I'm inside psql console!!! Though I need to use `local all postgres trust`, not `peer`.

Answer (score 1):

You should issue the psql command as amministrative user, which is `postgres` as default:
  `sudo -u postgres psql postgres`

(assuming you added the postgres directory to your path, or `sudo -u postgres ./postgresql-9.3/bin/psql postgres`)

Once you are in psql console, `\password postgres` and enter your new password